# Invalidating all $http caches in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

I have an Angular application with a number of services based on Angular's built-in `$resource` service.  Many of these use the `cacheFactory` to create their own independent caches.  However, I want to blow all of these away (both the named caches and the "default" `$http` cache) when someone logs out.  Right now I'm accomplishing this with `location.reload(true)`, which certainly works, but it would be nice to achieve it without the reload if it's possible without totally changing the structure of the application.

To clarify, I'm aware that I can remove the cached values if I have a reference to the individual cache in scope, but what I want to do is to remove all caches, across the board, without necessarily having to know what they're all called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can inject [`$cacheFactory`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) and get the cache object from the factory constructor (eg: `$cacheFactory.get('$http')`) and use `removeAll()` to cleanup all the cache. Use `destroy()` if you want to remove the cache object altogether.

In order to get all the cacheObject id's you could use [`$cacheFactory.info()`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/cacheFactory.js#L326) which will return object with summary info for each cache object `{id:'cacheObjId', size:'cacheSize'}`.

Example:-

```
angular.forEach($cacheFactory.info(), function(ob, key) {
   $cacheFactory.get(key).removeAll();
});
```

You could add `removeAll`/ `destroyAll` function to the cacheFactory so that you can use it anywhere else by decorating the `$cacheFactory`, something like this.

```
.config(['$provide',
    function($provide) {
      $provide.decorator('$cacheFactory', function($delegate) {
        $delegate.removeAll = function() {
          angular.forEach($delegate.info(), function(ob, key) {
            $delegate.get(key).removeAll();
          });
        }

        $delegate.destroyAll = function() {
          angular.forEach($delegate.info(), function(ob, key) {
            $delegate.get(key).destroy();
          });
        }
        return $delegate;
      });
    }
  ])
```

```js
angular.module('App', [])
  .config(['$provide',
    function($provide) {
      $provide.decorator('$cacheFactory', function($delegate) {
        $delegate.removeAll = function() {
          angular.forEach($delegate.info(), function(ob, key) {
            $delegate.get(key).removeAll();
          });
        }

        $delegate.destroyAll = function() {
          angular.forEach($delegate.info(), function(ob, key) {
            $delegate.get(key).destroy();
          });
        }
        return $delegate;
      });
    }
  ])
  .run(function($cacheFactory) {
    var value = 123;
    $cacheFactory('cache1').put('test', value);
    $cacheFactory('cache2').put('test', value);
    console.log($cacheFactory.info());
    $cacheFactory.removeAll();
    console.log($cacheFactory.info());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App">

</div>
```

Comment: is it there in angular 1.2.X?

Comment: @pankajparkar yes, it is available.

Comment: But wait a minute... then I have to individually retrieve each named cache, don't I?

Comment: That's certainly a plausible option, although I'd want to do it in one place.  I suppose altering the provider for $cacheFactory would achieve that though.

Comment: @Casey Why would you ever do that though (altering cache implementation)?

Comment: I mean what I want to avoid is having to change gazillions of resources to use a different service.  If I just fiddle with the $cacheFactory to "intercept" calls and remember the keys before passing to the default implementation I can do that.

Comment: @Casey `$cacheFactory.info()` should provide you all the cache objects. You can get all the keys from there and apply cacheFactory getter to get the instances and apply removeAll. I think that would be much better option that using an interceptor.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  Well if you want to edit the information in the comments here into your answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: One tip for others who try this:  you should exempt the templates cache; if you don't you'll start getting weird errors.