# Does Angular $http cache failed attempts?

Tags: angularjs, caching

I wasn't sure of this and didn't see the documentation on it. If I do a call as so...

```
...
return $http.get(baseUrl + '/lists/' + listObj.id, {cache: true})
    .then(function(resp){
          ...
          return null;
    }, function fail(err){
          return $q.reject(err);
    });
```

Angular would cache the http response and use that value next time I call the same http request. However, let say the connection fails or the list object id has since been created so the url now works. will will it have cached the failed attempt?

If it does do I have to manually dig into the $http.defaults.cache and remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't need to. When cache enabled angular keeps the promise object with respect to the url in cache and any subsequent requests will receive the same promise so that the call to the server is not made again. But in case of [unsuccessful](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L235) calls the cache [will get removed](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L1241) as the ajax call comes back from the sever. However if you make any more calls between that time you will eventually get the same failure for all those calls since they all have same promise.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks @PSL. One minor addendum question. I assume it's only true if the error code is not in the 200 range. Let's say I'm working with an api that gives something in the 200 range but produces an error as part of the response object. In that case, what's the most recommended way to force cache to be cleared for that id?

Comment: @ThinkBonobo You could have a generic logic in the interceptor listen to the response and check against your failure criteria on the response data, if it fails then remove the cache yourself provide the url as the key. The cache object id for http is `$http`. You could also provide your own cache name for the cache property. A related [answer on removing from cache is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168708/invalidating-all-http-caches-in-angular/31168742#31168742)