# How to refresh Angular $http cache?

Tags: angularjs, angular-cache

My service populates all items using `$http` and a cache when the controller is activated.  If I create a new item, by doing an `$http.post()`, what is the best way to refresh the cache?

The problem with the example below is the cached `getAll` call will return an outdated array:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myapp')
        .factory('items', itemsService)
        .controller('Items', itemsController);

    // myCache was created using angular-cache

    itemsService.$inject = ['$http', 'myCache'];
    function itemsService ($http, myCache) {

        var service = {
            getAll : function () {
                return $http.get('/api/item', myCache);
            },
            createNew : function (item) {
                return $http.post('/api/item', item);
            }
        };

        return service;
    }

    itemsController.$inject = ['items'];
    function itemsController (items) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.items = [];
        vm.item = {};

        activate();

        function activate() {
            items.getAll().then(function(response){
                vm.items = response.data || [];
            });
        }

        function createNew() {
            items.createNew(vm.item).then(function(response){
                vm.items.push(response.data);
            });
        }
    }

})();
```

**Edit #1 : Invalidating Cache**

I've modified the code to invalidate the cache when a new item is created.  The addition of the `$q` service, and manually `reject`ing or `resolve`ing the calls seems very tedious and bloated.

Is there a better way?

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myapp')
        .factory('items', itemsService)
        .controller('Items', itemsController);

    itemsService.$inject = ['$q', '$http', 'CacheFactory'];
    function itemsService ($q, $http, CacheFactory) {

        var _cache = CacheFactory.get('items') || CacheFactory('items');

        var service = {
            getItems : function(refresh) {
                var d = $q.defer();
                if (refresh) { _cache.invalidate(); }
                $http.get('/api/item', _cache).then(function(response){
                    d.resolve(response.data);
                }, function(err){ d.reject(err); });
                return d.promise;
            },
            createNew   : function(info){
                var d = $q.defer();
                $http.post('/api/item', info).then(function(response){
                    _cache.invalidate();
                    d.resolve(response.data);
                }, function(err){ d.reject(err); });
                return d.promise;
            }
        };

        return service;
    }

    itemsController.$inject = ['items'];
    function itemsController (items) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.items = [];
        vm.item = {};

        activate();

        function activate() {
            items.getAll().then(function(response){
                vm.items = response.data || [];
            });
        }

        function createNew() {
            items.createNew(vm.item).then(function(response){
                vm.items.push(response.data);
            });
        }
    }

})();
```

Comment: is myCache using $cache service?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  It's an `angular-cache` cache.

Comment: Here is the solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168708/invalidating-all-http-caches-in-angular

Comment: Interesting.  Sadly, that brings up other questions.  For example, I was maintaining the user's ID in the cache to prevent it from ever being used by another user.  If invalidating is the is the method I should probably move to session storage.

Comment: @Bhuneshwer : Is Edit #1 more "proper" or correct?